# Can I keep the old Kerdi drain flange when rebuilding a shower?

Tags: repair, shower, drain, flange, kerdi

My 1 yr old shower built by the contractor started leaking like a sieve. In my efforts to remedy the problem, I ended up demolishing the whole thing to the stud while throwing out moldy drywall and replacing moldy stud base plates.

He used a Kerdi shower base, but didn't apply any waterproofing to the sidewalls. I managed to save the Kerdi drain flange. It's in pretty good shape (see picture). Can I build a new Kerdi shower pan using the old flange, or should I get a new one?

[image: the original drain flange]